# Describe cloud formation stack in java aws sdk cannot filter by tag?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

When use aws java sdk to describe ec2 instances, there is an interface:

```
new DescribeInstancesRequest().withFilters(new Filter("tag:key", "value"),
```

You can filter instances by tags in this way, but when describe cloud formation stacks:

```
new DescribeStacksRequest() or new ListStacksRequest()
```

There is no such interface for filtering by tags, why? and how should I filter stacks by tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of filtering by tags option for `ListStacksRequest` it is still not that much of an 'effort' / 'performance hit' to iterate yourself over the stack list and do the filtering.

Because the number of stacks that you would have within your account would be much less than the number of instances that you would be having which can really get out of bounds if you have a heavy traffic and your ASG is spinning up instances in bulk.

So it made much more sense to have filtering option at-least for the instances.

Having said that it would definitely be helpful if the ListStacksRequest also had a `withFilters(new Filter("tag:key", "value")` option

What they do have, is the filtering by stack status as follows, to fetch a sub set of stacks based on their status

```
new ListStacksRequest().withStackStatusFilters(StackStatus... stackStatusFilters)
```